# Grabbing a JSON file from a website (specifically Trello.com)

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jsonp, crm

I am trying to grab a JSON file from a website (Trello.com). when I navigate to the web address of the JSON file in IE (or any browser) I am presented with the option to save it or to open it.

So I think to myself "this should be quite easy then".

However I've got some limitations on how to implement it.

I need to display data from the JSON on CRM 2013.

The displaying of the data isn't the issue, it's grabbing the JSON file from the website.

An example URL to use would be https://trello.com/1/boards/dgbi8Gng

I've been trying to use Ajax and JSONP but am encountering issues (likely due to my lack of experience with them).

Could anyone help out a frustrated fellow? Maybe some example code that could be implemented in CRM and a quick explanation?

Many Thanks

Comment: Doesn't look like that part of Trello supports JSONP.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include your application key in the url e.g.
https://trello.com/1/boards/dgbi8Gng?key=substitutewithyourapplicationkey

Then it's just a standard request (assuming you're using jQuery)

```
var url = "https://trello.com/1/boards/dgbi8Gng?key=[YOUR KEY]";
$.getJSON( url, function( data ) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Full details are here:
https://trello.com/docs/gettingstarted/#getting-an-application-key